# Killing a script while a function is active

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a main thread and another thread which starts after `threading.Timer(1,success).start()` calls it.

In the defined function success I need to kill the whole python script, I tried sys.exit() but that only ends the thread. I can't signal the main thread as the reason the timer went off was because the main thread took too long to respond, so there's no guarantee the signal would be read by the main thread.

I considered using os.exit() which works, but it's messy as the script is reloaded after a second by another program and memory fills up.

Comment: There is nothing your program can do about another process that relaunches it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the created thread with a timeout:

```
join(timeout=None)
```

Thus, it will not wait for completion.